# Run teamviewer on smaller-resolution X screen

Tags: linux, xorg, kubuntu, teamviewer

I am using [Teamviewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.teamviewer.market.mobile) to view my Kubuntu desktop from a rooted B&N Nook Simpletouch (Android 2.1). The desktop has 1680x1050 resolution and the Nook only shows the top 600x800 of that. Is it possible to start a second X screen (such as that opened on Ctrl-Alt-F8) at 600x800 and run Teamviewer on that?

Thanks.